# Using Same column for lag on which lag is performed

Tags: lag, windowing

I have an excel which has the below logic, and I am looking to convert the logic in PySpark.

| col1 (Either Y/N) | derivedvalue ( logic: if col1 = N then 1 else previous row value value +1) |
| --- | --- |
| N | 1 |
| Y | 2 |
| Y | 3 |
| N | 1 |
| N | 1 |
| Y | 2 |
| Y | 3 |
| Y | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

```py
counter_var =0
def cal_duplicate(input_flag):
    global counter_var
    if input_flag == 'N':
        counter_var=1
        return 1
    else:
        counter_var+=1
        return counter_var

df['duplicate_counter'] = df.apply(lambda x : cal_duplicate(x['flag']),axis=1)
```